# Passing headers with a request in DS.RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I never got it working passing headers in the RESTAdapter.

Below is an adapter I have running, the sessionService is registered through an initializer. I have tried just passing static options as well with no luck. It never reaches my logging point.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import config from '../config/environment';

/**
 * CategoryAdapter
 * @class adapters.Category
 * @extends DS.RESTAdapter
 */
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: config.api_host_static,
    headers: function() {
        console.log('authToken', this.get('sessionService').get('authToken'));
        return {
            "API_KEY": this.get('sessionService').get('authToken')
        };
    }
});
```

A jsbin here:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wuhilavinu/1/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`headers` needs to be a property, not a function. Make it a computed property by adding `.property()` to the function declaration.

```
headers: function() {
    return {
        "API_KEY": this.get('sessionService').get('authToken')
    };
}.property('sessionService.authToken')
```

Or, if you don't want to (or can't) rely on Ember's observers, make the property volatile so it's computed every time the adapter makes a request:

```
headers: function() {
    return {
        "API_KEY": this.get('sessionService').get('authToken')
    };
}.property().volatile()
```

This is all explained in the [API documentation for the RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_headers-customization).

Comment: Oh. My.
I was 100% sure I tried passing it as a property before. I must have done something wrong (like just passing this.get('authToken'). It works now. Duh! :-) Thanks!